# Connection ssh closed after successful authentication

Tags: ssh, 15.04

I have a big problem with the SSH login to my personal server. When I connect, I have this in the terminal:

```
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:

New release '16.04.3 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

You have new mail.
Connection to fiorenzodeluca.it closed.
```

The result of `ssh -vvv root@fiorenzodeluca` is:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 15.04 (GNU/Linux 3.18.41-20.el7.x86_64 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Fri Sep 22 17:39:52 UTC 2017

  System load:  0.0                Processes:           101
  Usage of /:   12.2% of 23.50GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 6%                 IP address for eth0: 138.201.105.234
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

7 packages can be updated.
7 updates are security updates.

Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:

New release '16.04.3 LTS' available.
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

You have new mail.

debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to fiorenzodeluca.it closed.
Transferred: sent 2152, received 2928 bytes, in 0.7 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3258.3, received 4433.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

What kind of problem do I have on my ssh connection? How I can resolve this?

Comment: Looks like your `~/.bashrc` on `fiorenzodeluca.it` fails. Or check `/var/log/auth.log` on `fiorenzodeluca.it`. Read `man scp` to copy those files to your system. Or, `vhostingservices.com` doesn't like `ssh`.

Comment: Check if your user has `/bin/bash` as shell and not `/bin/false`. This can be displayed with `cat /etc/passwd` and changed with `usermod -s /bin/bash your_user`.

Comment: the server hasn't problem with the ssh connections, and we can't see in the file cat /etc/passwd, because we can't entered in ssh connection.
How I can set another account as root, without enter in ssh?